# how to calculate image x and y coordinate as percentage in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

how to calculate image x and y coordinate as percentage in angular 4.i have posted my code below. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
getPercentage(elem){
  this.xAxis = Math.floor((elem.pageX/elem.target.naturalWidth)*100);
  this.yAxis = Math.floor((elem.pageY/elem.target.naturalHeight)*100);
  console.log(this.xAxis);
  console.log(this.yAxis);
}



<img width="50%"   height="50%" class="img-thumbnail" src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/n/3cpbpra_1422080.jpg?q=80" alt="" (click)="getPercentage($event)"/>
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with x and y co-ordinates in percentage...

Comment: I have to mark the icon on image based on x,y coordinates  in angular 4. The x and y coordinates value should be in percentage.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display an icon on top of an image. And the position of the icon will be relative to the image?

Comment: yes your right.. i will update my code in stackblitz within hour and will share the link.Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pure CSS/HTML thing.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<figure class="image-n-icon">
    <div class="heroimage"></div>
    <img src="placeholder.png" class="iconimage"></div>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS (styles.css)

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-n-icon {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 50rem;
}

.heroimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(https://images.wesaturate.com/photos/ehfzab_peterofgh.jpg?w=1000&dpr=2&auto=compress&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&ixlib=js-1.0.6);
    background-position: center;    
}

.iconimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    left: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
}
```

You said percentage, I used `rem`. Default browser font-size is 16px. I set html `font-size` as 62.5%. This translates to `1rem = 10px`. Throughout your code, you would use `rem` and you can simply manipulate the html `font-size` percentage to change the entire page sizes. Even if your user changes the browser font-size, your page scales accordingly.

It looks like below:

[image]

Comment: i have updated by stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgzyfy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have to mark the icon on image based on x,y coordinates in angular 4. i has to work on all device. so only i have marked my x coordinates as left and y coordinates as top percentage.

Comment: i am new to angular 4 for how to convert this jquery code into angular 4

Comment: var position = $('#div').position();
var percentLeft = position.left/$(window).width() * 100;
var percentTop = position.top/$(window).height() *100;